# I'm getting undefined method `file' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder when trying to use carrierwave without activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, form-for

I'm trying to do image uploads and in the past I used carrierwave and found it quite straight forward. This time round I am not using active record.

**Here is my model:**

```
class Garment
    include ActiveAttr::Model
    extend CarrierWave::Mount

    attribute :alternativeColour
    attribute :title
    attribute :image
    attribute :image2
    attribute :image3
    attribute :image4
    attribute :image5
    attribute :image6
    attribute :price
    attribute :favourite
    attribute :recommended
    attribute :gender
    attribute :productType
    attribute :size
    attribute :colour 
    attribute :collection

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

end
```

**My controller:**

```
class AdminpanelController < ApplicationController

  def index        
  end

  def new
    @garment = Garment.new
  end

  def create
    garment = Parse::Object.new("Garments")
    garment["title"] = params[:garment][:title]
    garment["price"] = params[:garment][:price].to_f
    garment["alternativeColour"] = params[:garment][:alternativeColour].to_bool
    garment["gender"] = params[:garment][:gender].to_i
    garment["recommended"] = params[:garment][:recommended].to_bool
    garment["productType"] = params[:garment][:productType].to_i
    garment["size"] = params[:garment][:size].to_i
    garment["colour"] = params[:garment][:colour].to_i
    garment["collection"] = params[:garment][:collection].to_i
    garment["image"] = params[:garment][:image]
    garment.save

    redirect_to adminpanel_index_path
  end
end
```

**My view (taken out some code to save space):**

```
<%= form_for :garment, :url => adminpanel_index_path, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :placeholder => "Title" %> <br \>
  <%= f.text_field :price, :placeholder => "Price" %> <br \>
  <%= f.file :image %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %> <br \>
<% end %>
```

Why could I be getting the error?

[image]

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ActionView::Helpers::FormHelper` no such method `f.file` this raise `undefined method file for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder`. You should use [`f.file_field`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field) in your form:

```
file_field(object_name, method, options = {})

<%= f.file_field :image %>
```